# Save the source of an open webpage from Safari with AppleScript

Tags: macos, safari, applescript

**How could I write a script that saves a webpage open in Safari to some path?**

(The code will be used for a more complicated script later, so a kludgy solution using System Events won't do.) A lot of googling to find a script that uses the save source function left me pretty uninformed so an answer to this might a the first on the internets. I've pasted some stuff that might be useful below.

### Potentially useful stuff

These two entries from the AppleScript dictionary for Safari look useful:

> **document** *n* [see also Standard Suite] : A Safari document representing the active tab in a window.
>
> properties:
>
> - **source** (text, r/o) : The HTML source of the web page currently loaded in the document.
> - **text** (text, r/o) : The text of the web page currently loaded in the document. Modifications to text aren't reflected on the web page.
> - **URL** (text) : The current URL of the document.

and later:

> **save** *v* : Save an object.
>
> **save** specifier : the object for the command
>
> - [**as** text] : The file type in which to save the data.
> - [**in** alias] : The file in which to save the object.

### A script that almost does what I want

This script does save an HTML document, but the output looks broken compared to files saved using Safari’s “Export as Page Source” function manually:

```
tell application "Safari"
(* Get a reference to the document *)
set myDoc to document of front window

(* Get the source of the page *)
set mySrc to source of myDoc

(* Get a file name *)
set myName to "Message_" & "0001" & ".html" -- the # will be modified later

tell application "Finder"
    (* Get a path to the front window *)
    set myPath to (target of front window) as string

    (* Get a file path *)
    set filePath to myPath & myName

    (* Create a brand new file *)
    set openRef to open for access (myPath & myName) with write permission

    (* Save the document source *)
    write mySrc to openRef

    (* Close the file *)
    close access openRef
end tell
```

This is what I’ve written so far:

### Scripts I've written so far

1. This is my first attempt:

   ```
   tell application "Safari"
       set pageToSaveSafariWindowIn to "Q:Ø:"
       set pageToBeSaved to front window
       save document pageToBeSaved as source in alias pageToSaveSafariWindowIn
   end tell
   ```

   Here are the resulting logs:

   ```
   tell application "Safari"
       get window 1
           --> window id 6017
       save document (window id 6017) as source in alias "Q:Ø:"
           --> error number -1700 from window id 6017 to integer
   ```

   and

   > error "Safari got an error: Can’t make window id 6017 into type integer." number -1700 from window id 6017 to integer
2. And another attempt:

   ```
   tell application "Safari"
       save source of document in "Q:Ø:"
   end tell
   ```

   which gives the result log:

   > error "Can’t get source of document." number -1728 from «class conT» of document

Comment: I understand that you want to get the full page that save would give you and not just plain html ?

Comment: Yes. In the end I went with a GUI/system events solution. I'm planning on posting the script when it's a bit more polished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a way to save a window full of tabs. The original UI handler was written by StefanK aka. Stefan Klieme of Macscripter fame. It considers webarchives file endings, when Safari is in doubt, you can adjust whether you want to overwrite or ignore already written files. It don't save duplicate tabs, and you may set a property to decide whether it shold close the tab when it is saved.

Please look at MacScripter, a direct link is in the script, for any updates.

You can overcourse use wget, but I settled for UI Scripting, as wget has download stuff that is already in your browser, and is a kluge to program as well.

```
    property tlvl : me
    # Release 1.0.1
    # © 2012 McUsr and  put in Public Domain under GPL 1.0
    # Please refer to this post: http://macscripter.net/post.php?tid=30892
    property shallClose : false # set this to false if you don't want to close the windows, just saving them
    property dontOverWriteSavedTabs : false # set this to true if you don't want to overwrite already saved tabs in the folder 
    script saveTabsInSafariWindowsToFolder
        property parent : AppleScript

        property scripttitle : "SafariSaveTabs"
        on run
            if downloadWindowInFront() then return 0 # activates Safari

            local script_cache
            set script_cache to my storage's scriptCache()

            set saveFolder to POSIX path of (getHFSFolder({theMessage:"Choose or create folder to save Safari-tabs in.", hfsPath:DefaultLocation of script_cache as alias}))
            if saveFolder = false then return 0 -- we were obviously mistaken, about what we wanted to do.

            my storage's saveParenFolderInScriptCache(saveFolder, script_cache)

            tell application "Safari"
                tell its window 1
                    local tabc, oldidx
                    set tabc to count tabs of it
                    if not tlvl's shallClose then
                        set oldidx to index of current tab
                        tell tab tabc to do JavaScript "self.focus()"
                    end if
                    local saveCounter
                    set saveCounter to 1 -- regulates setting of save folder to only first time in Safari.
                    repeat while tabc > 0
                        local theUrl, theIdx, theProtocol, alreadyClosed

                        set {theUrl, theIdx, alreadyClosed} to {URL of its current tab, index of its current tab, false}

                        if my isntAduplicateTab(theIdx, it) then

                            set theProtocol to my urlprotocol(theUrl)
                            if theProtocol is in {"http", "https"} then
                                # save it
                                set saveCounter to my saveCurrentTab(saveFolder, saveCounter)
                            else if theProtocol is "file" then
                                # make an alias of it 
                                my makeAliasForAFurl(saveFolder, theUrl)
                            end if
                        else
                            if tlvl's shallClose then
                                close current tab
                                set alreadyClosed to true
                            end if
                        end if

                        if not alreadyClosed and tlvl's shallClose then
                            close current tab of it
                            set tabc to tabc - 1
                        else if not tlvl's shallClose then
                            set tabc to tabc - 1
                            if tabc > 0 then tell tab tabc to do JavaScript "self.focus()"
                        end if
                    end repeat
                    # move forwards
                    if not tlvl's shallClose then
                        tell tab oldidx to do JavaScript "self.focus()"
                    end if
                end tell
            end tell
        end run


        to makeAliasForAFurl(destinationFolder, furl)
            local ti, tids, thefilePath
            set ti to "file://"
            set {tids, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, ti}
            set thefilePath to text item 2 of furl
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tids
            set theFile to POSIX file thefilePath as alias
            set theFolder to POSIX file destinationFolder
            tell application "Finder"
                make alias at theFolder to theFile
                # I don't care if there was one there from before, as it could equally
                # be a file with the same name.
            end tell
        end makeAliasForAFurl

        to saveCurrentTab(destinationFolder, timeNumber)
            tell application id "sfri" to activate
            tell application "System Events"
                set UI elements enabled to true
                tell process "Safari"
                    keystroke "s" using {command down}
                    tell window 1
                        repeat until exists sheet 1
                            delay 0.2
                        end repeat
                        tell sheet 1
                            if timeNumber = 1 then -- We'll set the savepath upon first call
                                keystroke "g" using {command down, shift down}
                                repeat until exists sheet 1
                                    delay 0.2
                                end repeat
                                tell sheet 1
                                    set value of text field 1 to destinationFolder
                                    click button 1
                                    delay 0.1
                                end tell
                            end if
                            keystroke return
                            delay 0.2
                            if exists sheet 1 then -- We are being asked if we want to overwrite already saved tab
                                if dontOverWriteSavedTabs then
                                    keystroke return # if it was already saved. We don't overwrite it
                                    click button 3
                                else
                                    keystroke tab
                                    keystroke space # we are  to overwrite
                                end if
                            else
                                try
                                    set dummy to focused of sheet 1
                                on error
                                    # click button 1 of panel of application "Safari"
                                    keystroke return

                                    delay 0.2
                                    if exists sheet 1 then -- We are being asked if we want to overwrite already saved tab
                                        if dontOverWriteSavedTabs then
                                            keystroke return # if it was already saved. We don't overwrite it
                                            click button 3
                                        else
                                            keystroke tab
                                            keystroke space # we are  to overwrite
                                        end if
                                    end if
                                end try
                            end if
                        end tell
                    end tell
                end tell
            end tell
            set timeNumber to timeNumber + 1
            return timeNumber
        end saveCurrentTab

        on downloadWindowInFront()
            tell application "Safari"
                activate
                set tabCount to count tabs of its window 1
                if tabCount  0 then set colons to true
            if (offset of "/" in aPath) > 0 then set slashes to true

            if colons and slashes then
                return null
            else if colons then
                set origDelims to ":"
            else if slashes then
                set origDelims to "/"
            else
                return null
            end if
            local tids
            set {tids, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, origDelims}
            if aPath = "/" then
                -- we return root when we get root
                set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tids
                return "/"
            end if
            local theParentFolder
            if text -1 of aPath is in {":", "/"} then
                set theParentFolder to text items 1 thru -2 of text 1 thru -2 of aPath
            else
                set theParentFolder to text items 1 thru -2 of aPath
            end if
            set theParentFolder to theParentFolder as text
            if slashes and theParentFolder = "" then set theParentFolder to "/"
            -- sets the root path if we got a folder one level below it
            if colons and (":" is not in theParentFolder) then set theParentFolder to theParentFolder & ":"
            -- we return volumename, if we are given volumename 
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tids
            return theParentFolder
        end parentfolder


        script storage
            property cachespath : ((path to library folder from user domain as text) & "caches:" & "net.mcusr." & scripttitle)

            on scriptCache()

                local script_cache
                try
                    set script_cache to load script alias (my cachespath)
                on error
                    script newScriptCache
                        property DefaultLocation : (path to desktop folder as text)
                        # edit any of those with default values
                    end script

                    set script_cache to newScriptCache
                end try
                return script_cache
            end scriptCache

            to saveScriptCache(theCache)
                store script theCache in my cachespath replacing yes
            end saveScriptCache

            to saveParenFolderInScriptCache(theFolderToSaveIn, script_cache)
                local containingFolder
                set containingFolder to (parentfolder of saveTabsInSafariWindowsToFolder for theFolderToSaveIn) & "/"
                local theLoc
                set theLoc to POSIX file containingFolder as alias
                set DefaultLocation of script_cache to theLoc
                my saveScriptCache(script_cache)
            end saveParenFolderInScriptCache
        end script
    end script
    tell saveTabsInSafariWindowsToFolder to run
```

**Enjoy**

Answer (score 5):

I have found what I believe to be a better / easier solution:

```
tell application "Safari"
activate
set URL of document 1 to "http://www.apple.com"
delay 5
set myString to source of document 1
end tell
set newFile to POSIX file "/Users/myUsername/test.html"
open for access newFile with write permission
write myString to newFile
close access newFile
```

Notes:

- "source of document 1" seems to be filled with the correct source text only AFTER the web page is fully loaded.   Thus the need for the delay.  Maybe you can use a lower delay.
- There are some solutions which recommend the use of curl. I haven't tried this, but I assume that for dynamically generated pages this could be problematic.
- The above works on OSX 10.8.4. Not tested for other versions.

Comment: Thanks, that `delay` was critical.

Answer (score 2):

Automator will do that. Here is the workflow - http://cl.ly/450m0Q21463p16322P1i.

Automator -> Actions -> Internet -> `Get Current Webpage from Safari` -> `Download Urls`.

Answer (score 2):

```
set hyperlink to "http://www.google.com/"

set sourceCode to (do shell script "curl " & hyperlink)

do shell script "echo " & quoted form of sourceCode & " >> /Users/name/Desktop/test.csv"
```

You can throw this in a repeat and it will append each source code from every listed stite to the end of your created document. i.e.

```
set hyperlink to "http://www.aRepetitivePageSite.com/2014?page="
set your_count to 1
repeat until your_count = 10
  set sourceCode to (do shell script "curl " & (hyperlink & your_count as string as text))
  do shell script "echo " & quoted form of sourceCode & " >> /Users/name/Desktop/test.csv"
  set your_count to your_count + 1
end repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were to do this task manually, you would View Source in Safari, Copy the source to the clipboard, go into an HTML source code editor and make a new document, Paste the source code in, choose Save and navigate to the Documents folder, name the document, and then Save it.

So when you want to write an AppleScript to do this task, a key thing is that you still want to use those same apps, but instead of running them manually, you will run them with AppleScript. A great AppleScriptable HTML source code editor is TextWrangler, which is free from Mac App Store.

Once you have both a Web browser (Safari) to get the HTML source from the network and an HTML source code editor (TextWrangler) to create and Save the HTML document, you can write a very small, very easy to write, very easy to read, very easy to maintain AppleScript like this one:

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    if document 1 exists then
        set theDocumentTitle to the name of document 1
        set theDocumentSource to the source of document 1
        tell application "TextWrangler"
            activate
            set theNewDocument to make new document with properties {name:theDocumentTitle, text:theDocumentSource}
            set theDocumentsFolderPath to the path to the documents folder as text
            set theSaveFilePath to theDocumentsFolderPath & theDocumentTitle & ".html"
            save theNewDocument to file theSaveFilePath
        end tell
    end if
end tell
```

… which will simply ask Safari to provide the name and source code of its frontmost document, and then ask TextWrangler to use that information to create and Save a matching HTML document in your Documents folder. Those are tasks that those 2 apps are each very good at. You sort of don’t have to ask twice or do a lot of explaining.